# Running schema recurring...We can't find the role for the user you wanted

Tags: magento2

Magento2 i tried to run some command required for adding new payment gateway

one of them 
up grade database : bin/magento setup:upgrade

but i got the below error can anyone help

Running schema recurring...We can't find the role for the user you wanted.

Comment: Welcome to the community! Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1):

You can open this file

> src/app/code/Magento/Authorization/Model/Acl/AclRetriever.php

line 68 and check why AuthorizationException is thrown.